# Can we able to use mulitple sparksessions to access two different Hive servers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario to compare two different tables source and destination from two separate remote hive servers, can we able to use two `SparkSessions` something like I tried below:-

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
  .appName("spark remote")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.160:3306/metastore?useSSL=false")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.175.160:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()

val sparkdestination = SparkSession.builder()
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.42:3306/metastore?useSSL=false")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.175.42:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

I tried with  `SparkSession.clearActiveSession() and SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()` but it isn't working, throwing the error below:

```
Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

is there any other way we can achieve accessing two hive tables using multiple `SparkSessions` or `SparkContext`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`SparkSession` `getOrCreate` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala)

which state that

> gets an existing [[SparkSession]] or, if there is no existing one,
>   creates a new one based on the options set in this builder.
>
> This method first checks whether there is a valid thread-local
>   SparkSession,   and if yes, return that one. It then checks whether
>   there is a valid global   default SparkSession, and if yes, return
>   that one. If no valid global default   SparkSession exists, the method
>   creates a new SparkSession and assigns the   newly created
>   SparkSession as the global default.
>       In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options specified in   this builder will be applied to the existing
>   SparkSession.

That's the reason its returning first session and its configurations.

Please go through the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#newSession()) to find out alternative ways to create session..

---

I'm working on <2 spark version. So I am not sure how to create new session with out collision of configuration exactly..

But, here is useful test case i.e [SparkSessionBuilderSuite.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSessionBuilderSuite.scala) to do that-
 ***DIY***..

Example method in that test  case

```
test("use session from active thread session and propagate config options") {
    val defaultSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val activeSession = defaultSession.newSession()
    SparkSession.setActiveSession(activeSession)
    val session = SparkSession.builder().config("spark-config2", "a").getOrCreate()

    assert(activeSession != defaultSession)
    assert(session == activeSession)
    assert(session.conf.get("spark-config2") == "a")
    assert(session.sessionState.conf == SQLConf.get)
    assert(SQLConf.get.getConfString("spark-config2") == "a")
    SparkSession.clearActiveSession()

    assert(SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() == defaultSession)
    SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()
  }
```

Comment: I cant able to find newSession() method in SparkSession. Is there any examples Please.

Comment: I did research on code which builds sparksession and gave above pointer. you have to check documentation methods. In fact,  I am working on <2 version of spark. please check methods like `setActiveSession` etc...

Answer (score 4):

I use this way and working perfectly fine with Spark 2.1

```
val sc = SparkSession.builder()
             .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://dbsyz1111:10000")
             .enableHiveSupport()
             .getOrCreate()

// Createdataframe 1 from by reading the data from hive table of metstore 1
val dataframe_1 = sc.sql("select * from <SourcetbaleofMetaStore_1>")

// Resetting the existing Spark Contexts
SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()

//Initialize Spark session2 with Hive Metastore 2
val spc2 = SparkSession.builder()
               .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://dbsyz2222:10004")
               .enableHiveSupport()
               .getOrCreate()

// Load dataframe 2 of spark context 1 into a new dataframe of spark context2, By getting schema and data by converting to rdd  API
val dataframe_2 = spc2.createDataFrame(dataframe_1.rdd, dataframe_1.schema)

dataframe_2.write.mode("Append").saveAsTable(<targettableNameofMetastore_2>)
```

Comment: how the above logic will work in spark 1.6.0, the same thrift will work on the hiveContext

Comment: Is this really working, i tried the exact same scenario and i cannot see any change in metastore connection when initialising spc2