# Create temporary SparkSession with enableHiveSupport

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, mapr

I am working on connecting to data in Hadoop that allows dynamic data type connections.

I need to be able to connect to Hive Thrift Server A, pull in some data, and then connect to Hive Thrift Server B and pull in more data.

To my understanding `enableHiveSupport` needs to be set up on the initial `SparkSession.builder`. Is there a way to add/change a thrift connection after the fact?

The only possible solution I have come across is using `newSession():SparkSession` however I am not sure if this is the correct solution that I am looking for.

I am using Spark 2.1, Hadoop 2.7

Comment: You can try to alter `hive.metastore.uris` in the SparkConf at runtime

Comment: I tried changing `hive.metastore.uris` during runtime using `sparkSession.conf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://B:port")` but when I run `sparkSession.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show` I still get back the original database list from thrift A.

Comment: Hmm. Well, if your tables aren't in some weird format, you could just read the filesystem location  behind both   tables

Comment: That is a good idea. Unfortunately that is not ideal for what I am working with.

Comment: Found a similar question with a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949246/can-we-able-to-use-mulitple-sparksessions-to-access-two-different-hive-servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the book **Spark The Definitive Guide** "After you create [SparkConf], the SparkConf is immutable for that specific Spark Application" Chambers and Zaharia (2018, p.276)

Answer (score 0):

```
   val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Example")
      .master("local")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://B:PortNumber")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: This builds a new SparkSession, but that doesn't work very well if you already have a SparkSession established.